# Cannot iterate through my linked list in c++

Tags: c++, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I've been working on this for a while now and I can't seem to figure out how to correctly iterate through my linked list. Right now, I can run the program, and it runs, but I do not get any results from the linked list. this is my code so far
here is what should happen. [image]

This is my result. [image] But this also crashes right away

```
#ifndef LList_h
#define LList_h

#include <iostream>
#include "node.h"

class LList
{
public:
    LList(void);            //constructor
    LList(const LList &);   //copy constructor
    ~LList();           //destructor

    LList *next;            //points to next node
    void push_back(const string &str);
    void push_front(const string &str);
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const LList& llist);
    LList &operator=(const LList &l);       
private:
    Node *_head;
    Node *_tail;

    string _str;
};

inline LList::LList(void) {
    cerr << "head = tail = 0 at 0024f8d0\n";

    _head = 0;
    _tail = 0;
}

inline void LList::push_back(const string &_str) {
    Node *p = new Node(_str);
    if (_tail == 0) {
        _tail = p;
    } else {
        _tail ->next(p);
        _tail = p;
    }        
}

inline void LList::push_front(const string &_str) {
    Node *p = new Node(_str);

    if (_head == 0) {
        _head  = p;
    } else {
        _head ->next(p);
        _head = p;
    }
}

ostream &operator <<( ostream &out, const LList & llist ) {
    for( LList *p = llist.front; p != 0; p = p -> next )
        out << p;

    return out;
}

LList & LList::operator=(const LList &l) {
    _head = 0;
    _tail = 0;

    return *this;
}
#endif
```

Comment: Please reduce your code to the minimum amount that's needed for the showing your problem.

Comment: what happens? what should happen?

Comment: Hi there, it's better to actually paste your error into the `code` blocks so the google crawler can index this page for people who have simmilar problems. Screen shots are not optimal for this.

Comment: @ereOn i don't mean that, I'm trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong and just be guided in the right direction. I don't want this done for me.

Comment: Others have rightfully noted about the way you should post questions. Here are some quick insightful notes about your code: 1. Did you notice that your implementation for push_back and push_front is identical? That can't be right. Most likely with push_back you want to work on the tail and push_front on the head. 2. You probably want to seperate the type LList from type Node. Type Node has no knowledge of head and tail, unless you want to update the head and tail for each node every time you do push_back or push_front which it seems from your code that you don't

Comment: Why you dont use debugger step by step? Ii will show your problem with very high chance.

Comment: Just one more observation - there's no need to post code which has been commented out...

Comment: after using the debugger, i receive an error in my loop iteration. the code that says `for( LList *p = llist.front; p != 0; p = p -> next )` receives an error saying unhandled exception: access violation reading location. what does that mean?

Comment: @JohnTinio Probably you're not setting `next` to `null` when it should be.

Comment: Your code mixes List and Node, uses Node functions you don't show us, has a `next` element in LList, which it uses to iterate (but never initializes). In `push_back()` you might be creating a singly linked list hanging off `_tail`. In `push_front()` you might be creating a separate list hanging off `_head`. Both functions do that only, if `Node::next(Node*)` does something rather unexpected. Please clean up your code a bit and post a complete, self-contained, compilable example.

Comment: Come on guys, stop it! This question is far from being the worst out there.

Comment: I'm extremely new at this and I'm trying to understand what is really going on with this

Answer (score 1):

It appears that there might be multiple problems in your original code. Given the discussion above and some of the responses, I'd recommend starting with something simpler. Get that working and then gradually expand it until you have what you were originally aiming for.

I would start by implementing a very simple singly-linked list without using classes. Define a struct containing a pointer to a struct of the same type and a data field (could just be an integer).

Create three or so variables of this struct and link them together so the first points to the second, the second points to the third, and the third points to NULL (by which you can identify the end of the list).

Then demonstrate iterating through the list. A very common idiom in C is as follows:

```
for (ptr = &first; ptr; ptr = ptr->next)
{
   printf("%p %d\n", ptr, ptr->data);
}
```

Make sure you understand why this works and use it to get comfortable with pointers and how linked lists work. Practice using the debugger to single-step through your list and make sure you understand how the loop terminates when you get to the end of the list.

Once you are happy with this, by all means wrap it up in a class and add methods like push_back() and push_front(), and overload some operators.

But make sure you are solid on the basics first.

Comment: I wish I had more time to do so. I try to make time, but there are not enough hours in the day for me.

Comment: @JohnTinio I do sympathise. No one became a great programmer overnight though. Keep at it.

Answer (score 0):

What does the `Node::next(Node *p)` function do?
If it sets the next field of `this` to `p`, then this code in your `push_front` function is probably wrong:

```
else
{
    _head ->next(p);
    _head = p;
}
```

Instead to should:

1. set `p.next` to `_head`. (head now follows `p`)
2. set `_head` to `p`. (the new head is `p`)

Comment: so then it should look like this then `p.next = _head` and `_head = p`

Comment: Yes, (15 char limit is annoying).

Comment: Ok, but when I try this, i receive an error message saying "Node *p Error: expression must have class type"

Comment: use `p->next = _head` instead. (`a -> member` is equivalent to `(*a).member`)

Comment: i get a new error message saying Error: a pointer to a bound function may only be used to call the function